# what does window.h mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably a really easy question

I've been searching, but I could not find what window.h means? Only some articles about C++ but not about javascript.

```
view: {
    fc: "",
    init: function() {
        var iframe = $("iframe")[0];
        var focused = true;
        var unfocusedTimeStart = null;
        var unfocusedTime = null;
        var loaded = false;
        var prevent_bust = 0;
        var done = false;
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            prevent_bust++;
        };
        setInterval(function() {
            if (prevent_bust > 0 && !done) {
                prevent_bust -= 2;
            }
        }, 1);
        var mySwfStore = new SwfStore({
            namespace: "BTCClicks",
            swf_url: "/js/storage.swf",
            onready: function() {
                var fcookie = mySwfStore.get("fcookie");
                var randomstring = md5(randomstring);
                if (fcookie == null) {
                    mySwfStore.set("fcookie", randomstring);
                }
                fcookie = mySwfStore.get("fcookie");
                if (fcookie != null) {
                    BTCClicks.view.fc = fcookie;
                }
            },
            onerror: function() {}
        });
        $("#viewFrame").load(function() {
            if (!loaded) {
                $.post("/ajax/vrequest", {
                    ad: window.h,
                    fc: BTCClicks.view.fc
                }).done(function() {
                    startTimer();
                });
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
```

Could someone explain what that means?

Comment: `window.height` or `window.h`.... `window.h` refers to a property `h` of the object referred by `window`

Comment: We would need to see what it is in reference to. Show the code.

Comment: That is the entire function inside the .js file.

Comment: The code you've shown can't be the entire function. (At least, not if you expect the code to actually _work_ - as it is it is incomplete and the browser would complain about a syntax error.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If refers to a variable named `h` in the global (window) scope

Whenever you make a global variable in JavaScript you can either refer to it by name or `window.[variableName]`

In this case you can either do

```
ad: window.h
```

or

```
ad: h
```

As long as there isn't another local variable named h